# Can a mindless creature make Int-based skill checks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, crafting

If I have a mindless creature that can use skills, like an Astral Construct using the Utility option of [Advanced Constructs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/feats/advanced-constructs-psionic), can that creature make Int-based skill checks?

I have a plan for my character that involves creating a large number of constructs and having them assist eachother to make very high DC skill checks, and I'm trying to find if there are any rules to prevent this.  I'd like to use the constructs for, among other things, crafting lots of mundane weaponry during my downtime.  I'll be there to supervise them while they work, but a Craft check is Int-based, so I'm unsure if it's legal for these constructs to be making these checks.

So, in general, can creatures that lack an ability score make skill checks using that score?  More specifically, can a mindless creature use the Aid Another option to help out with crafting an item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes.

From the [Intelligence](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores#TOC-Intelligence-Int-) description:

> Some creatures do not possess an Intelligence score. Their modifier is +0 for any Intelligence-based skills or checks.

But do note that Astral Constructs are mindless (= Int —), and as such have no skill points, as per the [construct type](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Construct). (Contrary to popular belief<sup>[citation needed]</sup>, not all constructs are mindless, e.g. [Robots](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/robot/machine-soldier-animated-object-fighter-1) have Intelligence scores.)

> Skill points equal to 2 + Int modifier (minimum 1) per Hit Die. However, most constructs are mindless and gain no skill points or feats. Constructs do not have any class skills, regardless of their Intelligence scores.